# kubectl get nodes not showing workers

Tags: kubernetes

I am following this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/) with 2 vms running CentOS7. Everything looks fine (no errors during installation/setup) but I can't see my nodes.

NOTE:

- I am running this on VMWare VMs
- kub1 is my master and kub2 my worker node

`kubectl get nodes` output:

```
[root@kub1 ~]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://kub1:8080

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

[root@kub2 ~]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://kub1:8080

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

nodes:

```
[root@kub1 ~]# kubectl get nodes
[root@kub1 ~]# kubectl get nodes -a
[root@kub1 ~]#

[root@kub2 ~]# kubectl get nodes -a
[root@kub2 ~]# kubectl get no
[root@kub2 ~]#
```

cluster events:

```
[root@kub1 ~]# kubectl get events -a
LASTSEEN   FIRSTSEEN   COUNT     NAME         KIND      SUBOBJECT   TYPE      REASON     SOURCE                    MESSAGE
1h         1h          1         kub2.local   Node                  Normal    Starting   {kube-proxy kub2.local}   Starting kube-proxy.
1h         1h          1         kub2.local   Node                  Normal    Starting   {kube-proxy kub2.local}   Starting kube-proxy.
1h         1h          1         kub2.local   Node                  Normal    Starting   {kubelet kub2.local}      Starting kubelet.
1h         1h          1         node-kub2    Node                  Normal    Starting   {kubelet node-kub2}       Starting kubelet.
1h         1h          1         node-kub2    Node                  Normal    Starting   {kubelet node-kub2}       Starting kubelet.
```

/var/log/messages:

```
kubelet.go:1194] Unable to construct api.Node object for kubelet: can't get ip address of node node-kub2: lookup node-kub2: no such host
```

QUESTION: any idea why my nodes are not shown using "kubectl get nodes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was that the `KUBELET_HOSTNAME` on `/etc/kubernetes/kubeletvalue` didn't match the hostname.

I commented that line, then restarted the services and I could see my worker after that.

hope that helps

Comment: After commenting KUBELET_HOSTNAME in /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.env and restarting the nodes, it worked. Now i can see all the nodes listed with kubeclt get no

Comment: I could not see /etc/kubernetes/kubeletvalue. I am using kubernetes 1.12

Comment: me too. I cannot see  /etc/kubernetes/kubeletvalue. nor  /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.env. I am using k8s v1.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your scenario, but I have solved it after 3-4 hours of efforts.

> Solved

I was facing this issue, because my docker cgroup driver was different than kubernetes cgroup driver. 
Just updated it to `cgroupfs` using following commands mentioned in [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/).

```
cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs"]
}
EOF
```

Restart docker service `service docker restart`.
Reset kubernetes on slave node: `kubeadm reset`
Joined master again: `kubeadm join <><>`

It was visible on master using `kubectl get nodes`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after installing k8s using kubespray on fedora31, and to debug the issue, tried to run a random container directly using docker run that failed with:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown.
```

this is a known problem cause by cgroup version on fedora 31, and the fix is to update grub to use the previous version:

```
sudo dnf install grubby

sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```